# Delete a scipt that autoloads that was run

Tags: installation

I ran a script that made a panel tab in N tools and I want to delete it from autoloading. Where are they stored? BTW I've blender Zip installs

thanks

Comment: If you simply ran the script and did not import it as an add-on, Blender should automatically remove the code on exit.

Comment: Try right clicking on the UI of the panel and _"Edit Source"_  if successful report back the path of that file.  It could be an enabled addon, registered script in startup file,  or in startup folder.

Comment: I’m noticing the context of the question. It sounds like you installed an add-on. How and where exactly did you get and run this script? Can you share the script with us?

Answer (score 2):

Afaik you cannot delete the script from the outside, but you CAN disable its execution temporarily so you can get instide the blend file. Run blender from the system command line with the disable autoexec flag, like this:

```
blender —disable-autoexec
```

…and then open your file with that instance of Blender.

PS: note that if blender has not been added to PATH on Windows, this will not work directly. First, either navigate with Windows Explorer to blender’s program files and open the command line there, or just open the command line and navigate to the directory first:

```
cd C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender

.\blender —disable-autoexec
```

The .\ on the blender line is necessary in PowerShell.

Of course, you can also just add blender to PATH, but that’s an OS-specific question.

Comment: Thanks, Where to I run that line? In Blender Text Editor? The added tab to the N Panel is not specific to a .blend file. Its now part of my blender UI even with New files.

Comment: @OthoapProto Its not in blender. This task is running blender anew via your operating system’s command line, and giving it special arguments. The command line is available in Command Prompt or Windows PowerShell on Windows, LXTerminal in most Linux distributions.

Comment: Thanks All, I had forgotten the tab I wanted to delete I made with an Addon Called PME (Pie Menu Editor). DUMP of me. thanks again to all.